# How to fill two dropdowns one depending on the other carrying a json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have 2 dropdowns with car manufacturer and models!

I am trying to fill the first dropdown with the manufacturers that are in Json in the content "makes:[]" when selecting manufacturer
I wanted to load the second dropdown with the models of that json "models:[]"

An example I want to do is the same as this site:
[SITE](https://www.cars.com/shopping/)

```
<div class="_13dlk"><select aria-label="Make" name="makeId">
                            <option selected="" value="0">All Makes</option>
                            <option value="20001">Acura</option>
                            <option value="20047">Alfa Romeo</option>
                            <option value="20002">Am General</option>
                            <option value="20003">Aston Martin</option>
                            <option value="20049">Audi</option>
                            <option value="20050">Avanti Motors</option>
                            <option value="20051">Bentley</option>
                            <option value="20005">BMW</option>
                            <option value="33583">Bugatti</option>
                            <option value="20006">Buick</option>
                            <option value="20052">Cadillac</option>
                            <option value="20053">Chevrolet</option>
                            <option value="20008">Chrysler</option>
                            <option value="20009">Daewoo</option>
                            <option value="20055">Daihatsu</option>
                            <option value="20012">Dodge</option>
                            <option value="20058">Eagle</option>
                            <option value="20014">Ferrari</option>
                            <option value="20060">FIAT</option>
                            <option value="41703">Fisker</option>
                            <option value="20015">Ford</option>
                            <option value="35354491">Genesis</option>
                            <option value="20062">Geo</option>
                            <option value="20061">GMC</option>
                            <option value="20017">Honda</option>
                            <option value="20018">Hummer</option>
                            <option value="20064">Hyundai</option>
                            <option value="20019">INFINITI</option>
                            <option value="20065">International</option>
                            <option value="20020">Isuzu</option>
                            <option value="20066">Jaguar</option>
                            <option value="20021">Jeep</option>
                            <option value="36365359">Karma</option>
                            <option value="20068">Kia</option>
                            <option value="33663">Koenigsegg</option>
                            <option value="20069">Lamborghini</option>
                            <option value="20024">Land Rover</option>
                            <option value="20070">Lexus</option>
                            <option value="20025">Lincoln</option>
                            <option value="20071">Lotus</option>
                            <option value="20072">Maserati</option>
                            <option value="20027">Maybach</option>
                            <option value="20073">Mazda</option>
                            <option value="47903">McLaren</option>
                            <option value="20028">Mercedes-Benz</option>
                            <option value="20074">Mercury</option>
                            <option value="20075">MINI</option>
                            <option value="20030">Mitsubishi</option>
                            <option value="20076">Morgan</option>
                            <option value="20077">Nissan</option>
                            <option value="20032">Oldsmobile</option>
                            <option value="36785838">Pagani</option>
                            <option value="20079">Panoz</option>
                            <option value="20034">Peugeot</option>
                            <option value="20080">Plymouth</option>
                            <option value="36847100">Polestar</option>
                            <option value="20035">Pontiac</option>
                            <option value="20081">Porsche</option>
                            <option value="20036">Qvale</option>
                            <option value="44763">RAM</option>
                            <option value="20037">Rolls-Royce</option>
                            <option value="20038">Saab</option>
                            <option value="20084">Saleen</option>
                            <option value="20039">Saturn</option>
                            <option value="20085">Scion</option>
                            <option value="20228">smart</option>
                            <option value="33584">Spyker</option>
                            <option value="20040">Sterling</option>
                            <option value="20041">Subaru</option>
                            <option value="20042">Suzuki</option>
                            <option value="28263">Tesla</option>
                            <option value="20088">Toyota</option>
                            <option value="20089">Volkswagen</option>
                            <option value="20044">Volvo</option>
                            <option value="20045">Yugo</option>
                        </select></div>
```

MODEL

```
<div class="_13dlk"><select aria-label="Model" name="modelId">
                            <option selected="" value="0">All Models</option>
                            <option value="42843">Aventador</option>
                            <option value="36376457">Aventador S</option>
                            <option value="36783430">Aventador SVJ</option>
                            <option value="20994">Diablo</option>
                            <option value="21195">Gallardo</option>
                            <option value="56867">Huracan</option>
                            <option value="36711959">Huracan EVO</option>
                            <option value="21683">Murcielago</option>
                            <option value="36629010">Urus</option>
                        </select></div>
```

> ```
> JSON
> ```

```
{
          "makes": [
            {
              "id": 20001,
              "label": "Acura",
              "name": "Acura",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20047,
              "label": "Alfa Romeo",
              "name": "Alfa Romeo",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20002,
              "label": "Am General",
              "name": "Am General",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20003,
              "label": "Aston Martin",
              "name": "Aston Martin",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20049,
              "label": "Audi",
              "name": "Audi",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20050,
              "label": "Avanti Motors",
              "name": "Avanti Motors",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20051,
              "label": "Bentley",
              "name": "Bentley",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20005,
              "label": "BMW",
              "name": "BMW",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 33583,
              "label": "Bugatti",
              "name": "Bugatti",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20006,
              "label": "Buick",
              "name": "Buick",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20052,
              "label": "Cadillac",
              "name": "Cadillac",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20053,
              "label": "Chevrolet",
              "name": "Chevrolet",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20008,
              "label": "Chrysler",
              "name": "Chrysler",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20009,
              "label": "Daewoo",
              "name": "Daewoo",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20055,
              "label": "Daihatsu",
              "name": "Daihatsu",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20012,
              "label": "Dodge",
              "name": "Dodge",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20058,
              "label": "Eagle",
              "name": "Eagle",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20014,
              "label": "Ferrari",
              "name": "Ferrari",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20060,
              "label": "FIAT",
              "name": "FIAT",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 41703,
              "label": "Fisker",
              "name": "Fisker",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20015,
              "label": "Ford",
              "name": "Ford",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 35354491,
              "label": "Genesis",
              "name": "Genesis",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20062,
              "label": "Geo",
              "name": "Geo",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20061,
              "label": "GMC",
              "name": "GMC",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20017,
              "label": "Honda",
              "name": "Honda",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20018,
              "label": "Hummer",
              "name": "Hummer",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20064,
              "label": "Hyundai",
              "name": "Hyundai",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20019,
              "label": "INFINITI",
              "name": "INFINITI",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20065,
              "label": "International",
              "name": "International",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20020,
              "label": "Isuzu",
              "name": "Isuzu",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20066,
              "label": "Jaguar",
              "name": "Jaguar",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20021,
              "label": "Jeep",
              "name": "Jeep",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 36365359,
              "label": "Karma",
              "name": "Karma",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20068,
              "label": "Kia",
              "name": "Kia",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 33663,
              "label": "Koenigsegg",
              "name": "Koenigsegg",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20069,
              "label": "Lamborghini",
              "name": "Lamborghini",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20024,
              "label": "Land Rover",
              "name": "Land Rover",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20070,
              "label": "Lexus",
              "name": "Lexus",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20025,
              "label": "Lincoln",
              "name": "Lincoln",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20071,
              "label": "Lotus",
              "name": "Lotus",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20072,
              "label": "Maserati",
              "name": "Maserati",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20027,
              "label": "Maybach",
              "name": "Maybach",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20073,
              "label": "Mazda",
              "name": "Mazda",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 47903,
              "label": "McLaren",
              "name": "McLaren",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20028,
              "label": "Mercedes-Benz",
              "name": "Mercedes-Benz",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20074,
              "label": "Mercury",
              "name": "Mercury",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20075,
              "label": "MINI",
              "name": "MINI",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20030,
              "label": "Mitsubishi",
              "name": "Mitsubishi",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20076,
              "label": "Morgan",
              "name": "Morgan",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20045,
              "label": "Yugo",
              "name": "Yugo",
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            }
          ],
          "models": [
            {
              "id": 20773,
              "label": "CL",
              "name": "CL",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 47843,
              "label": "ILX",
              "name": "ILX",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 48964,
              "label": "ILX Hybrid",
              "name": "ILX Hybrid",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 21266,
              "label": "Integra",
              "name": "Integra",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 21380,
              "label": "Legend",
              "name": "Legend",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 21422,
              "label": "MDX",
              "name": "MDX",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 36306155,
              "label": "MDX Sport Hybrid",
              "name": "MDX Sport Hybrid",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 21685,
              "label": "NSX",
              "name": "NSX",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 21831,
              "label": "RDX",
              "name": "RDX",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 21782,
              "label": "RL",
              "name": "RL",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 51867,
              "label": "RLX",
              "name": "RLX",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 58167,
              "label": "RLX Sport Hybrid",
              "name": "RLX Sport Hybrid",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 21784,
              "label": "RSX",
              "name": "RSX",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 21879,
              "label": "SLX",
              "name": "SLX",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 22237,
              "label": "TL",
              "name": "TL",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 57287,
              "label": "TLX",
              "name": "TLX",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 22248,
              "label": "TSX",
              "name": "TSX",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 22362,
              "label": "Vigor",
              "name": "Vigor",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 32888,
              "label": "ZDX",
              "name": "ZDX",
              "makeId": 20001,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 20325,
              "label": "164",
              "name": "164",
              "makeId": 20047,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 57327,
              "label": "4C",
              "name": "4C",
              "makeId": 20047,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 30021900,
              "label": "4C Spider",
              "name": "4C Spider",
              "makeId": 20047,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 34963,
              "label": "8c Competizione",
              "name": "8c Competizione",
              "makeId": 20047,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 36314247,
              "label": "8c Spider",
              "name": "8c Spider",
              "makeId": 20047,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 21238,
              "label": "Giulia",
              "name": "Giulia",
              "makeId": 20047,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 22172,
              "label": "Spider",
              "name": "Spider",
              "makeId": 20047,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28881
              ]
            },
            {
              "id": 36285237,
              "label": "Stelvio",
              "name": "Stelvio",
              "makeId": 20047,
              "visibleIn": [
                0,
                28880,
                28881,
                28444
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

Comment: you should take a look a this tutorial : https://makitweb.com/auto-populate-dropdown-with-jquery-ajax/ check the DEMO : https://makitweb.com/demos/auto-populate-dropdown-with-jquery-ajax

Comment: We don't really need all that data. It's enough to just post some examples that's enough to illustrate the data and test with. You should also include your attempt to solve it yourself. Where exactly are you stuck? Have you done any research?

Comment: I'm stuck with how popular the first "select" with the json tag **makes:[]**
After popular the 1 select would have to load the json **models:[]** using the **makeId** indicator:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.each` to populate your first dropdown then whenever user select any option from that dropdown just get the value(makeId) and then use `filter` to filter your `models` array and then append only values to second dropdown where `makeId` and `id` matches .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose json is this ..
var json = {
  "makes": [{
      "id": 20001,
      "label": "Acura",
      "name": "Acura",
      "visibleIn": [
        0,
        28880,
        28881,
        28444
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 20047,
      "label": "Alfa Romeo",
      "name": "Alfa Romeo",
      "visibleIn": [
        0,
        28880,
        28881,
        28444
      ]
    }
  ],
  "models": [{
      "id": 20773,
      "label": "CL",
      "name": "CL",
      "makeId": 20001,
      "visibleIn": [
        0,
        28881
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 21782,
      "label": "RL",
      "name": "RL",
      "makeId": 20047,
      "visibleIn": [
        0,
        28881
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 51867,
      "label": "RLX",
      "name": "RLX",
      "makeId": 20047,
      "visibleIn": [
        0,
        28880,
        28881,
        28444
      ]
    }
  ]
}


let dropdown = $('select[name=makeId]');
let modelId = $('select[name=modelId]');

dropdown.append('<option>Choose one</option>');
$.each(json.makes, function(key, entry) {
  dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.id).text(entry.name));
});

//onchange of make id
dropdown.change(function() {
  ids = $(this).val(); //get value
  modelId.empty();
  modelId.append('<option>Choose ..</option>');
  //filter your json..get only json array where id matchs
  var items = $(json.models)
    .filter(function(i, n) {
      return n.makeId === parseInt(ids);
    });
  //add to your options
  $.each(items, function(index, value) {
    modelId.append("<option>" + value.name + "</option>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="_13dlk">
  <select aria-label="Make" name="makeId">
  </select>
</div>
<div class="_13dlk">
  <select aria-label="Model" name="modelId"></select>
</div>
```